# Symfony 4 Profiler error in info url

Tags: php, symfony, profiler, symfony4

I'm testing symfony 4 and I found a strange thing abbout symfony 4 profiler and web toolbar.

My test project URL is: http://localhost/sf4

I created my first controller etc etc and it works perfectly but when I check into the profiler web toolbar and want to check the controller the toolbar double the project URL like this:

Normal profiler url: http://localhost/sf4/_profiler/b2e473?panel=request

Profiler url when trying to check controller:
http://localhost/sf4/**sf4**/_profiler/open?file=src\Controller\LuckyController.php&line=19#line19

This problem obviously create and error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?? or eventually what to check?
Thank you for your help
S.

---

Update 1:
My project is running on xampp php 7.2 and yes it is under the directory sf4.
It is just a test project not production environment.
The htaccess file has been created installing apache-pack package.

Comment: We need some more info in order to help you. Your project is hosted under the path `/sf4`. How did you accomplish that? Did you create a .htaccess-file? How does your server config look like? Please update your question with these details

Comment: I've added some details....which of server config info would like to evaluate??

Comment: Basically, how does your apache know, where the symfony project's public directory is? Do you have a vhost setup?

Comment: No i did not edit any apache config file, I prefer to move index.php into sf4 instead of subfolder public.

Comment: Ok, can you add to the question how you changed the folder structure and where you moved files to, if you moved them into different folders? Alternatively, if you like, I can write an answer that explains how to setup a Symfony project in a subfolder using apache and then you can use that as a guide how to restructure your project.